# Como calcular o logaritmo de um número em qualquer base em java?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como calcular o logaritmo de um número na base 2 e em qualquer outra base. Sei que no java dá pra se calcular o logaritmo de um número na base 10 usando a função `Math.log10`, mas não sei como calcular o log de um número qualquer na base 2 por exemplo.

Agradeço desde já a atenção de todos!

Comment: Quando você fala em "base" se refere à base do logaritmo, certo?

Comment: Seria alguma coisa parecida com isso? Math.log10(30)/Math.log(2)

Comment: @LINQ isso mesmo LINQ, me refiro à base do logaritmo.

Comment: @Marcondes tentei fazer isso, mas não deu certo. Continua dando uma resposta errada pros cálculos que eu to fazendo.

Comment: @Marcondes [quase o que você falou](http://latex2png.com/output//latex_36c20f1e5559e1ca631a715de3d2f9c3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
class Logaritmos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(log(2, 128));
        System.out.println(log(5, 625));
        System.out.println(log(100, 1000));
        System.out.println(log(7, 49));
    }

    public static double log(double base, double valor) {
        return Math.log(valor) / Math.log(base);
    }
}
```

O método `log` é o que você quer e sinta-se livre para copiar e colar em sua aplicação. O método `main` serve de teste. Segue abaixo a saída correta e esperada:

```
7.0
4.0
1.4999999999999998
2.0
```

Observe apenas que este `1.4999999999999998` era para ser `1.5`, mas ao trabalhar com `double` sempre há uns detalhes referentes à precisão.

[**Vaja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/OctHim)

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Resolveu meu problema!

Comment: Para quem parar aqui sem maiores contextos, a matemática do assunto: `log_b (a) = log(a)/log(b)`; log de a na base b é igual à divisão de log de a pelo log de b

Comment: http://latex2png.com/output//latex_36c20f1e5559e1ca631a715de3d2f9c3.png